# Save compressed files in file system

Tags: c#, .net, file, zip

I want to save multiple files in one Zip file on my disc. This Zip is created but his type is "Compressed (zipped) Folder" and is impossible to open. Error: "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'path' is invalid. Can I make it normal .Zip file somehow?

```
int i = 0;
await using var ms = new MemoryStream();
{
    using var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
    {
        foreach (var s in stepwiseData)
        {
            //streamWriter.Write(s);
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry($"Name {i.ToString()}");
            i++;
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(entry.Open()))
            {
                writer.Write(s.ToArray());
            }
        }
                    
        var folder = @"C:\Temp\test\";
        var fileName = "TestName.zip";
        var fullPath = folder + fileName;

        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, bytes);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put the `var bytes = ms.ToArray();` outside the `using var archive` block

Comment: Why are you using an intermediate memory stream, instead of writing directly to a file-stream? And why are you using `await using` to dispose a memory stream, that is essentially free to dispose?

Comment: My fault, I put ";" at the end of line with using